# R: Append Rows of One Column to the Adjacent Column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I want to bind the rows of two columns in the same data frame together. I currently do this by uniting them and splitting them. Is there a more succinct way of doing this?

[image]

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

Citrus_1 <- c("Lemon", "Lime", "Orange")
Citrus_2 <- c("Grapefruit", NA, NA) 
Fruit_List <- data.frame(Citrus_1, Citrus_2)

Fruit_List %>%
  unite(Citrus_List, c("Citrus_1", "Citrus_2"), sep = ",") %>%
  cSplit(., "Citrus_List", sep = ",", direction = "long") %>%
  filter(!is.na(Citrus_List))
```

EDIT: Poor choice of column name. Updated to to Citrus_List

Comment: Try `data.frame(Fruit_list = na.omit(unlist(Fruit_List, use.names = FALSE)))`

Comment: I made a poor choice with the column names. I've updated it to Citrus_List. Apologies about my mistake, but could you change the comment please?

Comment: In that case, `unlist(Citrus_List`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tidyverse approach:

Your data:

```
Citrus_1 <- c("Lemon", "Lime", "Orange")
Citrus_2 <- c("Grapefruit", NA, NA) 
Fruit_List <- data.frame(Citrus_1, Citrus_2)
```

The list as dataframe with only a column:

```
Fruit_List %>% 
        gather("Citrus_1", "Citrus_2", key = "Fruit_var",value = "Citrus_List",na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
        select(Citrus_List)
```

Comment: Wanted the tidyverse solution, but it seems like it should be `select(Citrus_List)` instead of `select(Fruit List)`

Comment: It's true, I have corrected the name of the selected variable

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` to do this.  `unlist` the 'Fruit_List', remove the `NA` (`na.omit`) and create a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(Fruit_list = na.omit(unlist(Fruit_List, use.names = FALSE)))
#  Fruit_list
#1      Lemon
#2       Lime
#3     Orange
#4 Grapefruit
```